# Using robot and presskeyevent in java

Tags: java, awtrobot

I'm working with a project. It uses android to control the activities in game, especially in racing game.

I can connect the device with PC and send the sensor information for 3 elements X, Y, Z. It works really good in word or file explorer ( I use it to move the cursor up, down, left and right ). But, when I use it in game ( flash game, dirt2, road rash, ... ) it doesn't work.

The cause I think is the Class `Robot` that I have used! It doesn't work when the other apps like Game are working. So, is there anyway to simulate the keyboard that work with in my case?

Thanks a lot for helping me! best regard!

Comment: I would suggest this is may be a focus issue. You may need to try a do a mouse click on the centre of the screen to try a force the application into focus